# Text replace challenge (regex)

Tags: regex

I can't solve a problem. Perhaps it is impossible to achieve what I want.

GOAL: use only replace function to remove all text except the email address.

I have a text with email in: `Start text some other text 2828 text my.address@mail.com some additional text.`
Regular expression to select email: `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]+@[\w\d\-\._]+\.\w{2,12}`

Regular expression works perfectly to find an email address, but it didn't work to remove all letters from an email.

Below print screen shows what I got as a result when apply replace function in the text editor:
[image]
As results I used regexp `.*([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]+@[\w\d\-\._]+\.\w{2,12}).*`, and replace it on `$1`. Sadly this workflow give me broken email.

I used email as an example, the same result I got for any other data types as URLs, IPs, phones, names, cities, zips etc.

Can anyone unveil a solution to this problem?
Thank you a lot.

PS I am not interested in using math() function, because of this function isn't presented in most of the text editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should make the first part [non greedy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) `.*?` or else the `.*` will match upon the `@` and after that just giving up 1 match to satisfy the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]+`

If it is not greedy it will capture `my.address@mail.com` instead of  `s@mail.com`

[`.*?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]+@[\w\d\-\._]+\.\w{2,12}).*`](https://regex101.com/r/HYVuMr/1/)

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your regular expression is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

**Find:** `(.*?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]+@[\w\d\-\._]+\.\w{2,12}\s?(.*?)`

**Replace:** `$1$2`

---

**Input:** `Start text some other text 2828 text my.address@mail.com some additional text`

**Output:** `Start text some other text 2828 text some additional text`